# Can't build the corona for android

Tags: android, coronasdk

I create a basic physic in corona, now I want to build it for android but the problem is its saying that the java jdk is required even if I already installed the JDK.

any thoughts regarding this issue?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corona doesn't use the last version of JDK. You should have 6.4.1 or something like that. I'm not sure about the version but you can find it in corona's site. It doesn't accept newer versions.